# Porque o PHP retorna zero ao subtrair elementos de um objeto?

Tags: php

Percebi um comportamento do PHP que não conhecia, é o seguinte:

para exemplificar estou pegando um XML e utilizando a função `simplexml_load_string()`. Veja abaixo(ignore a falta de verificações, é apenas um exemplo):

```
$simplexml_load_string = simplexml_load_string($my_xml_url);

if(isset($simplexml_load_string->item))
{
    $myarray = array();
    foreach($simplexml_load_string->item as $key => $value){
        $myarray['myelement'] = $value->myelement;  // 0 or 0.0
        $myarray['myelement2'] = $value->myelement2; // 0.000091
    }
}
```

Até aqui temo um array `$myarray` com o elemento de chave `myelement` e o elemento de chave `myelement2` com os valores que podem ver comentados no código acima, quais são respectivamente "$value->myelement == 0 or 0.0" e "$value->myelement2 == 0.000091". Agora tentarei fazer uma conta com os elementos do `$myarray` abaixo.

```
$result = $myarray['myelement2'] - $myarray['myelement'];
// $result recebe 0
```

Então eu fiz alguns teste para entender o que estava acontecendo, primeiro verifiquei a precisão no php.ini, estava OK, depois dei um `echo 0.000091 - 0;` ou `echo 0.000091 - 0.0;` e recebi 0.000091 como esperado. Então fui verificar o `$myarray` e percebi que os elementos do array não eram valores comuns, e sim "SimplexXMLElement Object([0] => 0.000091)", qual faz todo sentido, pois atribui um elemento do objeto retornado pela função xml, mas ainda estava sem entender o que acontecia para sempre receber 0(e ainda não sei). Mas decidi fazer o teste abaixo:

```
$simplexml_load_string = simplexml_load_string($my_xml_url);

if(isset($simplexml_load_string->item))
{
    $myarray = array();
    foreach($simplexml_load_string->item as $key => $value){
        $myarray['myelement'] = (float)$value->myelement;  // 0 or 0.0
        $myarray['myelement2'] = (float)$value->myelement2; // 0.000091
    }
}
$result = $myarray['myelement2'] - $myarray['myelement'];
// $result recebe 0.000091
```

E meu problema foi resolvido, mas a dúvida continua, porque o PHP me retorna 0 quando é um "SimplexXMLElement Object([0] => 0.0)" e me retorna o valor esperando quando é um "float"?

Comment: aparentemente é um bug no  php como pode se ver neste topico (esta em ingles)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035163/php-read-decimal-integers-from-xml-attributes

Comment: Agradeço o link.