# Undefined ao tentar utilizar o JSON válido recebido

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Estou com um problema chato de encontrar o erro, já estou horas procurando aqui. Estou recebendo um JSON do PHP utilizando JQuery, eu consigo visualizar ele como pode ver abaixo o resultado da resposta "data":

```
{
    "sucesso": 1,
    "dados": {
        "BTC_YAMRUB": {
            "result": 500000,
            "url_redirect": "https:\/\/mysite.com\/?rid=1229109",
            "https": 1,
            "link_permanente": "mysite",
            "nome": "MySite",
            "exchange_rates": 500000,
            "idade": "3 anos e 1 m\u00eas",
            "wmid": null,
            "pais_nome": "Brasil",
            "moeda_from": "Bitcoin BTC",
            "moeda_to": "Yandex money RUB",
            "rank_from": "14",
            "rank_to": "38",
            "reviews": [{
                "cliente_site": "52",
                "positivo": "0",
                "comentario": "0",
                "negativo": "0"
            }],
            "offer": {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 0,
                "in": 1,
                "out": 500000,
                "amount": 121436.1859,
                "minfee": 0,
                "fromfee": 0,
                "tofee": 0,
                "minamount": 0,
                "param": "manual"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

porém ao tentar qualquer umas das linhas abaixo eu recebo `undefined`.

```
console.log(data[0].length);
console.log(data.length);
console.log(data.dados.length);
```

O código javascript:

```
function getRates()
{
    $("#gif_load").show();

    $.post(URL_SITE + '/api/exchangers', {from: $("#from").val(), to: $("#to").val()}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

        if(textStatus == "success") {

            $("#exchangers tbody tr").remove();

            console.log(data.length); // undefined
            console.log(Object.keys(data).length); // 2

            if(data.dados.length > 0)
            {
                  $.each(data.dados, function(index, el) {
                      console.log(el.result);
                  });
            }
          }

     });

}
```

O código do PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../includes/_conect.php");

$limit_blocktraill = 300;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url_invalid  = URL_SITE . '/';
$url_valid = str_replace(":80", "", $url_invalid);

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' && strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], $url_valid) !== false)
{
    if(isset($_POST["from"]) && isset($_POST["to"]))
    {
        $from = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["from"]);
        $to = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["to"]);

        #--------------------MemCached-----------------------------------------
        $memCached = new Memcached();
        $memCached->addServer('localhost', 11211);

        if ($dados = $memCached->get('rank_moeda')) {
            if ($memCached->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND) {
                $exchangers = 0;
            }else{
                $exchangers = $dados;
            }
        }

        if(count($exchangers) > 0)
        {
            echo json_encode(array("sucesso" => 1, "dados" => $exchangers));

        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("sucesso1" => 1, "dados" => array()));
        }

    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("sucesso2" => 0, "Erro" => "Error"));
    }

}else{
    echo json_encode(array("sucesso3" => 0, "Erro" => "Error"));
}
```

Verifiquei toda a resposta no https://jsonlint.com/ e está OK. A algum outro teste que posso fazer para encontrar o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Tem como colocar o código JS que faz e trata a requisição?

Comment: Pra já, editei a pergunta com o código JS.

Comment: Editei com o código PHP também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que o JavaScript não retorna o tamanho do objeto, apenas de *arrays*. Por isso está dando o erro *undefined*.

Lembrando que toda vez que você retornar *(observar os colchetes no exemplo abaixo)*:

```
{
    "sucesso": 1,
    "dados": [{
        ...
    }]
}
```

O JavaScript irá interpretar como um *JSON Array* e automaticamente adicionará a propriedade `length`.

E toda vez que você retornar:

```
{
    "sucesso": 1,
    "dados": {
        ...
    }
}
```

O JavaScript irá interpretar como um *JSON Object* e **não** adicionará a propriedade `length`

Mas há uma forma de percorrer um objeto. Basta retornar todas as `keys` do objeto e depois executar um `for..of`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$.post('SUA-URL', {}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

    if(textStatus == "success") {

        $("#exchangers tbody tr").remove();

        /* Captura as keys */
        let keys = Object.keys(data.dados);

        /* Exibe a quantidade */
        console.log( keys.length );

        /* Verifica se há keys */
        if ( keys ) {

            /* Percorre os valores através da key */
            for (let d of keys) {
                console.log( data.dados[d]);
            }
        }
      }

 });
```

Ou você pode retornar todos os valores com `Object.values`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$.post('SUA-URL', {}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

    if(textStatus == "success") {

        $("#exchangers tbody tr").remove();

        /* Captura todos os valores */
        let values = Object.values(data.dados);

        /* Exibe a quantidade de valores */
        console.log( values.length );

        /* Verifica se há valores disponíveis */
        if ( values ) {

            /* Percorre todos os valores */
            for (let v of values) {
                console.log( v );
            }
        }
      }

 });
```

Comment: E como eu faria para retornar assim `[{
    "sucesso": 1,
    "dados": {
        ...
    }
}]` ?

Comment: @PerduGames com o código (PHP) postado não tem como saber muita coisa, mas você deve remover os valores `BTC_YAMRUB` quando salvar os valores da variável. Seria mais ou menos como fazer: ` $dados[] = $dados_da_moeda ` ao invés de `$dados[ $id ] = $dados_da_moeda;`

Comment: Entendi, muito boa sua resposta, marcando como resolvido, agradeço a ajuda, salvou a madrugada da dor de cabeça que iria ser para descobrir que era isso kkkkkk

Comment: Eu tento converter para array com (array) o "offer", porém não consigo também.

Comment: @PerduGames se possível edita sua pergunta posta o código como você está armazenando esses valores na variável. Ou pode postar no https://pastebin.com

Comment: Está correto, é a variável "offer" que está com sendo atribuída errada por algum motivo. Ao invés da string estou recebendo 0.

Comment: Eu estava convertendo ela para float sem querer por causa desse problema aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278176/porque-o-php-retorna-zero-ao-subtrair-elementos-de-um-objeto que acabei fazendo um (float) em tudo, mas me esqueci das strings kkkk, agora está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, os dados devem ser contados assim:

```
Object.keys(data).length // retorna 2
```

Dados:

```
Object.keys(data.dados).length // retorna 1
```

Pra simplificar pode fazer assim:

```
var tmp = Object.keys(data);
console.log(tmp.length);
console.log(tmp.dados.length);
```

Comment: os ... é só explicando que tem mais dados, desconsidere ele.

Comment: Eu imaginei que fosse, editei a resposta com mais exemplos,

Comment: Fiz o teste e está OK.

Comment: Desculpa, eu salvei sem terminar de por os detalhes da explicação. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Mas como utilizo os dados? e porque tem que ser assim? Sempre fiz do jeito que está acima e funcionou. Acho que o problema ser outra coisa.

Comment: Pra ser franco eu nunca vi ninguém medir o tamanho das chaves de um **Json** sem ser da maneira que eu mostrei, eu fiz o teste com o seu e funcionou, mas da maneira que você mostrou só consegui com **Arrays**: `[1,['a',b],'teste']`

Comment: console.log(tmp); me retorna `(2) ["sucesso", "dados"]
0
:
"sucesso"
1
:
"dados"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)` porém console.log(tmp.dados.length); me retorna indefinido também.

Comment: Você fez o teste direto no console ou chamando a função?

Comment: chamando a função.

Comment: Tem razão, nem fez sentido o ultimo exemplo que eu fiz. Devo estar com sono mesmo